# Node Promise properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm developing an importer, for each category i have to create the category and their sizes, for example in this input JSON:

```
const input_json = {
"categories": [
        {
            
            "title": "category title",
            "sizes": [
                {
                    
                    "title": "size title",
                    "slices": 8,
                    "flavors": 4,
                    
                },
                {
                    "id" : "",
                    "title": "size title 2",
                    "slices": 8,
                    "flavors": 4,
                    
                }
            ]
       }
   ]
}
```

but the problem is that sizes need to know the category id, so i'm trying to do it like this:

```
const prepareCategories = (body) => {
    let category_promises = []

    for (let i = 0; i < body.categories.length; i++) {
        const categoryBody = body.categories[i]

        let object_category = {
           ......
        } // set the object
        
        categoryPromise = nmCategorySvcV2.create(object_category) 
        
        categoryPromise.size = categoryBody.sizes

        category_promises.push(
            categoryPromise,
        )
    }
    
    return category_promises
}

......

          let category_promises = prepareCategories(input_json) // passing the input 

            Promise.all(category_promises).then((categories) => {
                console.log(categories)
                
            })
```

but when I see the result of Promise.all the sizes property is not displayed, only the properties of the category actually created.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `size` on the *promise* (which doesn't have any meaning). Instead you need to wait for the promise to be resolved and then set the size on its result:

```js
const categoryPromise = nmCategorySvcV2.create(object_category)
 .then(result => Object.assign(result, { size: categoryBody.sizes }))
```

(By the way you were missing a declaration for `categoryPromise`.)

The code could become a bit clearer using `await` syntax:

```js
const prepareCategories = body => body.categories.map(async categoryBody => {
  const object_category = {
    //......
  } // set the object
  const categoryData = await nmCategorySvcV2.create(object_category)
  categoryData.size = categoryBody.sizes 
  return categoryData
})
```